# Roblox Lua MouseButton1Click not working

Tags: lua, roblox

Some context would be the following, These are for TextButtons but they are built in the script. So i build them but if i don't place the if statement around the code i get an error saying that CL1 is nil. BUT i know CL1 isn't always Nil throughout the code because i assign it before the button is shown visible. I'm really unsure how to fix it, i've tried everything. Any input is appreciated.

Here is the Code:

```
if(CL1 ~= nil) then
CL1.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    spawnChosen = true
    spawnPicked = Center1Spawns
end)

CL2.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    spawnChosen = true
    spawnPicked = Center2Spawns
end)

CL3.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    spawnChosen = true
    spawnPicked = Center3Spawns
end)



RL1.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    spawnChosen = true
    spawnPicked = Right1Spawns
end)



RL2.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    spawnChosen = true
    spawnPicked = Right2Spawns
end)



RL3.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    spawnChosen = true
    spawnPicked = Right3Spawns
end)


LL1.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    spawnChosen = true
    spawnPicked = Left1Spawns
end)



LL2.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    spawnChosen = true
    spawnPicked = Left2Spawns
end)



LL3.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    spawnChosen = true
    spawnPicked = Left3Spawns
end)



VP1.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    print("Clicked!")
    spawnChosen = true
    spawnPicked = Victory1Spawns
end)


VP2.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
    print("Clicked!")
    spawnChosen = true
    spawnPicked = Victory2Spawns
end)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Check to make sure it's not behind another gui
2) If the click isn't working, the MouseButton1Down might
3) tables are helpful sometimes

```
local Buttons = {VP2,VP1,LL3,LL2,LL1,RL3,RL2,RL1,CL3,CL2,CL1,}
local Spawns = {Victory2Spawns,Victory1Spawns,Left3Spawns,Left2Spawns,Left1Spawns,Right3Spawns,Right2Spawns,Right1Spawns,Center3Spawns,Center2Spawns,Center1Spawns,}

for i,v in ipairs(Buttons) do
    if not v:IsA"ImageButton" and not v:IsA"TextButton" then
        print("It's not a button")
    end
    v.MouseButton1Down:connect(function()
        print("Saw Mouse Button Down")
        spawnChosen = true
        spawnPicked = Spawns[i]
    end)
    v.MouseButton1Click:connect(function()
        print("Saw click")
        spawnChosen = true
        spawnPicked = Spawns[i]
    end)
end
```